# Using mock to unit test my API having reference to multiple respositories

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, abp

I have a API implemented using ABPZero framework using EFcore. I have done integration test using sqlite in memory db as per the suggestions on documentation. But I am puzzled when trying to do unit test on the same API using mock[assuming that mock is faster in terms of execution]

I have referece to different repositoreis on that method. Should I be mocking the service or the repository on the testcase?

```
   public PagedResultDto<PatientSearchDTO> Search(PatientInpu 
                                            PatientInput)
              {     
             List<PatientSearchDTO> patientSearch = new 
            List<PatientSearchDTO>();
        int totalCount=0;
        try
        {   
            var filterText = PatientInput.Filter.Trim().ToLower();

            //Get the patients filtered usinng the filter text.
            var result = this._demoRepository.GetAll().Where(x =>
                                                       x.Dem_Firstname.ToLower().Contains(filterText)
                                                        );
            var treatment = _treatmentRepository.GetAll();                
            // Get the treatments for the pateints we fetched.
            var demotreatment = (from tdemo in result
                                 join treat in treatment on tdemo.Dem_Acu_Id equals treat.trm_acu_id into g1
                                 from treat in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()                                    
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Acu_Id = tdemo.Dem_Acu_Id,
                                     FirstName = tdemo.Dem_Firstname.Trim(),
                                     Surname = tdemo.Dem_Surname.ToUpper().Trim() + (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tdemo.Dem_Alias) ? string.Empty : " (" + tdemo.Dem_Alias.Trim() + ")"),
                                     MaidenName = tdemo.Dem_Maidname.Trim(),
                                     DOB = tdemo == null ? DateTime.MinValue : tdemo.Dem_Dob,
                                     RegistrationNumber = tdemo.Dem_RegNo == null ? string.Empty : tdemo.Dem_RegNo.Trim(),
                                     Photo = tdemo.Dem_Photo,                                         
                                     TreatmentStartDate = treat == null ? Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000") : Convert.ToDateTime(treat.trm_tr_startdate)
                                 });
```

This is the constructor of the test,

```
  public PatientServiceTests()
    {
        service = LocalIocManager.Resolve < IPatientService >();
        //creating set up data.
        SetUp();
    }

    private void SetUp()
    {
        //Arrange
        UsingIdeasDbContext(context =>
        {
            context.Demos.Add(new TDemo
            {
                Id = 1,
                Dem_Acu_Id = "1",
                Dem_Firstname = "Jack",
                Dem_Surname = "Jill",
                Dem_Maidname = "",
                Dem_Dob = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-30),
                Dem_Alias = "JJ",
                Dem_RegNo = "123456"
            });
           context.TTreatment.Add(new TTreatment
            {
                trm_acu_id = "1",
                trm_cycle = "4207-1",
                trm_tr_startdate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-1),
            });
    }

   [Fact]
    public void Should_SearchPatients()
    {
         PatientInpu input = new PatientInpu () { Filter = "ja", 
         Sorting = "FirstName ASC", SkipCount = 0, MaxResultCount = 10 };
        var result = service.Search(input);
        result.Items.Count.ShouldBe(1);
    }
```

What will be the best way to unit test this method? in -memory or Mock?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have an abstraction layer over the database implementation. Your caller doesn't need to know the implementation details.

Having said that, expose the DB functionality via an interface and while unit testing, mock out the interface/service (use can use mocking frameworks like Moq or write a custom mock).